# how to bind a click event to an element in another click element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The second click event that is binded to $("play") does not execute. How can i bind another click event under a click event? I cant get the data newNumber if i write the second click event outside the first click event.

This piece of code is in the slide() function.

```
var that = this;
$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(set);
    var newNumber = [num, numb, list]; //the value needed by click event that is binded to "play"

    $("play").click(newNumber, function() {
        num = newNumber[0];
        numb = newNumber[1];
        list = newNumber[2];
        that.slide(image, num, list, numb);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is easy, you don't! Never add event handlers inside event handlers.

Comment: What do you want to archive? Click on #stop should execute clearInterval and the play-stuff? Currently it is binding a click-handler to play every time you click stop.

Comment: why don't you add `new Number=[num, numb, list]` line to the `play` event?

Comment: Well first off your 'play' ID needs a '#.' Second, if you want two elements to do something on the same click event then give them a common class instead of calling their individual IDs.

Comment: The `$('play')` selector implies an element `<play />` which doesn't exist. Try binding to the id `$('#play')` or class `$('.play')` depending on the appropriate situation and your given markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this - the right way is to trigger :

```
var that = this;
var newNumber = [];
$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(set);
    newNumber = [num, numb, list]; //the value needed by click event that is binded to "play"

   $("play").click() //or $("play").trigger('click')
});

$("play").click(function() {
        num = newNumber[0];
        numb = newNumber[1];
        list = newNumber[2];
        that.slide(image, num, list, numb);
});
```

---

- Use **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** to bind a click event explicitly.
- Define the array newNumber in *global scope*, to use it in other events.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably confusing two important terms: `binding` and `triggering`. You probably want to trigger the second event within the handler of the first, but you want to bind both to begin with anyway. Otherwise, you run into issues of binding the second event multiple times but never really triggering it.

You normally want to **bind an event once** at the start, but **you can trigger it as many times** as you need.

```
var that = this;
var newNumber;
$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(set);
    newNumber = [num, numb, list]; //the value needed by click event that is binded to "play"
    $("#play").click(); // trigger the second <=======
});
$("#play").click(function() {
    num = newNumber[0];
    numb = newNumber[1];
    list = newNumber[2];
    that.slide(image, num, list, numb);
});
```

But the question I would ask is, **What Does 'this' refer to?**